# Css issue in product grid for an ecommerce

Tags: html, css

How to fix the problem in following image in css (I am new to css/html)

[image: Product List]

The problem is if product label is too long, `add button` slides down. And if label is short it slides up.

Here is css and html.

```
<div class="product-container">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/sample_prod.jpeg" alt="Product name"  class="ProductTopCell img-rounded"></a>
    <div class="product-container-bottom">
        <p class="product-label"><a href="#">Buxted Free Range Skinless Chicken Breast Fillets (430g)</a></p>
        <p style="font-weight:600">Rs 43<small>/Kg</small></p>
        <div class="product-add-button"><span class="quantity-cell">qty <input type="number" class="quantity-number-cell" value="1"> kg</span><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Add</button></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product-container">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/sample_prod.jpeg" alt="Product name"  class="ProductTopCell img-rounded"></a>
    <div class="product-container-bottom">
        <p class="product-label"><a href="#">Buxted Free Range Range Rang Skinless Chicken Breast Fillets (430g)</a></p>
        <p style="font-weight:600">Rs 43<small>/Kg</small></p>
        <div class="product-add-button"><span class="quantity-cell">qty <input type="number" class="quantity-number-cell" value="1"> kg</span><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Add</button></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product-container">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="img/sample_prod.jpeg" alt="Product name"  class="ProductTopCell img-rounded"></a>
    <div class="product-container-bottom">
        <p class="product-label"><a href="#"> Breast Fillets (430g)</a></p>
        <p style="font-weight:600">Rs 43<small>/Kg</small></p>
        <div class="product-add-button"><span class="quantity-cell">qty <input type="number" class="quantity-number-cell" value="1"> kg</span><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Add</button></div>
    </div>
</div>


 .product-container .thumbnail {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.product-container {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C2BEB7;
    width: 172px;
    padding: 0 5px 15px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    height: 280px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.product-container-bottom {
    background-image: url(img/Dotted-line.gif);
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    padding-top: 10px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.product-label {
    line-height: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    direction: ltr;
}

.product-label a {
    color: #004B91;
}

.product-add-button {
    margin-top:3px;
    text-align:right;

    vertical-align:baseline;
}

.quantity-cell {
    font-size:12px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right:7px;
}

.quantity-number-cell {
    width:30px;
    font-size:13px;
    height:90%;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the option of reducing the area of the information of the product is not that bad if we consider that with a flexible box your problem is going to persist. The thing is that you can provide the whole information, just clip the area that shows it and if the user hovers over it, then you show the whole information.

I'll usually choose the option of fixed size and explain the client the limitations of description, like number of characters, specially because that also forces them to standardize the information and helps the user to get better data and comparisons.

Other option is to position the elements that you want absolute in the page, but that most probably is going to be impossible due to design, number of products and the fact that you are not sure of the sizes of the text and some content may end up on top of something else.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, using a `<table>` here is acceptable, and will solve you problem. (Contrary to popular belief, not **all** tables are evil).

My example:

```
<table class="products">
    <tr class="figures">
        <th>
            <a href="#">
                <figure>
                    <img src="img/sample_prod.jpeg" alt="Product name" class="ProductTopCell img-rounded">

                    <p>Very very long description that will definitely break the line, and force the price to go down a bit. That will cause everything else in the row to also go down, even though they weren't directly affected.</p>
                </figure>
            </a>
        </th>
        <th>
            <a href="#">
                <figure>
                    <img src="img/sample_prod.jpeg" alt="Product name" class="ProductTopCell img-rounded">

                    <p>Description</p>
                </figure>
            </a>
        </th>
        <th>
            <a href="#">
                <figure>
                    <img src="img/sample_prod.jpeg" alt="Product name" class="ProductTopCell img-rounded">

                    <p>Description</p>
                </figure>
            </a>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="price">
        <td>Rs 34/Kg</td>
        <td>Rs 34/Kg</td>
        <td>Rs 34/Kg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="quantity">
        <td><label>qty <input type="number" min="0" value="1"> kg</label> <button>Add</button></td>
        <td><label>qty <input type="number" min="0" value="1"> kg</label> <button>Add</button></td>
        <td><label>qty <input type="number" min="0" value="1"> kg</label> <button>Add</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<style>
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .products {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .products th {
        font-weight: normal;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .products td, .products th {
        padding: 10px;
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    .price {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .quantity input {
        width: 3em;
    }
    .quantity button {
        padding: .2em .5em
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Another possibility is to use stuff like `display: table` on a list.

Comment: Agreed, people need to understand that tables are not the problem, they serve a purpose and that purpose is displaying tabular data. It's when people use them for regular layouts that the problems arise.

Answer (score 0):

As i see it you have two options.

**First**
Set min-height with CSS on your product label. Below is an example.

```
min-hieght:150px
```

**Second**
You could trim the string and make them all exact same lenght.

```
var myString= " My string";
var numberOfChars = 10;
var finalString = myString.substr(0,numberOfChar) + "...";
```

Comment: See my comments on both other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your product-label should be of fixed height, add following attr to your product-label class

```
height: 100px;
```

Furthur suggestion, for the line following (RS 43/kg) you might want to add a class of fixed height also. In case it has a variable height.

Comment: And what if I don't want it fixed height? What if it should be dynamic based on the amount of text?

Comment: In that way your <table> solution is easier to implement :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be to trim the string using JavaScript.

`var startLabel = "label text";`

`var labelLength = "12";`

`var label = startLabel.substr(0,labelLength);`

Comment: What? Why would you kill content in favor of style? -1.

Comment: A lot of websites use just previews of the actual header/label, showing a full header/label when the item of interest is pressed. When browsing a site you wanna catch a quick glimpse of whatever is available, and more detailed information when you've chosen that exact item. Of course you can show the full label on the page for that item.

Comment: Only that may not be the case here. And it's not something you should force on the OP, as it's not the only solution.

Comment: OP never stated if he wanted to keep the full length label or not. He just simply wanted a method to fix the uneven positioning of the add button and I proved one. I did not state that this is the only solution and I'm certainly not forcing anything upon him as it is his choice to accept my answer or not, I'm simply providing a quick and simple to understand solution that does the job and is easily modified to fit other needs.